# how to read my blob column from mysql to string type in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, blob

how to read my blob column from mysql to string type in hibernate

I have try this way but alway return me:
[B@196f4b5

```
        Article article2=f.daoArticle.findById(article.getSrcUrl());

        String vbody = article2.getArticle();
           System.out.println(vbody);
\\hbm
 <class catalog="ariso" name="countaword.ariso.dao.Article" table="article">
  <id name="srcUrl" type="java.lang.String">
   <column length="200" name="SrcUrl"/>
   <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <property column="Article" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="article" type="text" not-null="true" length="10485760"/>
 </class>

\\
```

any helps? It took me 3 hours!!!

Comment: <class catalog="ariso" name="countaword.ariso.dao.Article" table="article">
  <id name="srcUrl" type="java.lang.String">
   <column length="200" name="SrcUrl"/>
   <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <property column="Article" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="article" type="text" not-null="true" length="10485760"/>
 </class>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check the following page from the interwebtubes:

https://www.hibernate.org/76.html

It describes how to create a custom hibernate UserType to map a CLOB/BLOB to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this class](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/BlobStringType.html) from the spring-orm library. Be aware, though, that Springs (B|C)LOB handling relies on a lot of framework classes that need to be initialized correctly. I think you should either switch to using spring for handling hibernate completely or just use the class' source as inspiration.